# C# Console.In.Peek(); returns endless results after initial key press

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I'm trying to create a thread which I check for key presses in a console application. The idea being if no keys are pressed for 10 minutes the user is logged out.

I spawn this little thread where I try to use Console.In.Peek(); to get a key press without reading the key so the main thread can actually ReadKey / ReadLine issue free. However, I am finding that upon pressing the very first key Console.In.Peek(); stops blocking and that loop goes over and over without obstruction.

Any ideas why Console.In.Peek(); stops blocking after the first key press and any ideas how to fix it? Thanks so much!

```
 public static void AuthTimer()
    {


        while (true)
        {
            Console.In.Peek();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.ReadKey();
           Console.WriteLine("auth timer");
            if (Authentication.Authenticated == true)
            {
                Authentication.AuthTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

    }
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT

Thanks to the comments here by the fine folks on Stackoverflow I gave up on Console.In.Peek() and switched to

if (Console.KeyAvailable == true)

It doesn't take the key out of the stream and seems to block until a key is pressed so it effectively solves my issue! Thanks everyone for the comments.

Comment: Also, I added int b = 0; b = Console.In.Peek(); it seems to return 10, any idea why the value would be 10? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you actually remove (read) the pressed character from the main thread before peeking for them again?

Comment: `Peek` does not change the state of the `TextReader` `Console.In` exposes. If you peek multiple times and no keys are pressed in between it will always return the same value. What did you expect?

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. If the return value from Peek() changed I guess I could then compare previous value with new value to determine that it is in fact a unique key press. However it seems to always return 10 regardless of the key being press.

Comment: It is not sensible code, it doesn't use the return value of Peek().  Only if it returns -1 should you start the 10 minute timer.  And cancel it again when it doesn't.  Only if the timer expires should you declare the user inactive.

Comment: Thanks Hans, however I want a keypress event to extend that timer. I don't want to authenticate + start a timer, and then after 10 minutes log the user out if they are doing something. I am trying to keep the timer updated every time they press a key i.e. timer gets reset every key stroke.

Comment: what you might do is poll and sleep.. when peek returns, enter a second loop of poll and sleep, waiting for peek to block again after the key has been removed.

Comment: Max: That is the exact issue, Peek() never seems to block again. I've tried on multiple computers and waited over 10 minutes.... never blocks again...

Comment: @xmael91nt The answer does not belong in the question.